# COM events, C# to JNI with binary compatibility

Tags: c#, com

Replacing a VB6 OCX project with C#. Basic functionality is present, but events are not forwarding to JNI listeners. The VB6 control provides two proxies to COM objects defined in C++, a manager and a device. The manager provides a PlugPlayConnectionChange event, this event is acquired and executed by the C# implementation, but is never forwarded to the JNI.

The IDL for the manager is:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(GUID),
    dual,
    helpstring("IManager Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IManager : IDispatch
{
    [propget, id(DISPID_VALUE), helpstring("property device")]
        HRESULT Device(
            [in] long lIndex,
            [out,retval] IDispatch ** ppDevice );
};

enum
{
    DISPID_ONPLUGPLAYCONNECTIONCHANGE = 1
};
[
    uuid(GUID),
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("_IManagerEvents")
]
dispinterface _IManagerEvents
{
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(DISPID_ONPLUGPLAYCONNECTIONCHANGE)]
            HRESULT PlugPlayConnectionChange(
                long laType,
                BSTR bstrID,
                VARIANT_BOOL bAdd);
};
```

The C# implementation I have so far is:

```
public delegate void PlugPlayConnectionChangeEventHandler(int aType, string id, bool add);

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("GUID")]
[ProgId("ManagerProxy")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[ComSourceInterfacesAttribute("_IManagerEvents")]

public class ManagerProxy : IManager
{
    public static event PlugPlayConnectionChangeEventHandler PlugPlayConnectionChange;

    public ManagerProxy() : base()
    {
            manager = new Manager();
            manager.PlugPlayConnectionChange += MGR_PlugPlayConnectionChange;
    }

    internal void MGR_PlugPlayConnectionChange(int aType, string id, bool add)
    {
        ...
        PlugPlayConnectionChange?.Invoke(aType, id, add);
    }
}
```

I tried using `GetType()` in the attribute definition, but the IDE didn't like it. The string may be a better option, as I need 5 events in the other proxy. I have tried both `"_IManagerEvents"` and `"_IManagerEvents.PlugPlayConnectionChange"` neither worked.

Any information or suggestions about what I am missing (or doing wrong) would be appreciated.

One curious note, the JNI implementation provides two additional classes: one with a single leading underscore, the other with two leading underscores; `_ManagerProxy` & `__ManagerProxy`. It doesn't seem like these need to be implemented in the C#, but that conclusion is drawn from the simple example given in ["How to: Raise Events Handled by a COM Sink"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Fall in the pit of success with [ComSourceInterfacesAttribute(typeof(_IManagerEvents))].  That way you can't forget to define the interface and, with [ComVisible(true)], have the definition appear in the type library so the event subscriber has a shot at implementing the interface.  When testing it, be sure to unregister the original COM server.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I updated the `[ComSourceInterfacesAttribute()]` with the `typeof`, and unregistered the previous COM component (which I had not done), but still seem to be missing something.